# DecorationImage doesn't show the image - Flutter

Tags: image, dart, flutter, assets

I couldn't find anything related to this, so I guess I am doing something very wrong. I am trying to display a `DecorationImage` inside `BoxDecoration`, but nothing shows on my screen at all.

I try to show the related asset with `Image.asset('assets\\test.png');` and that works with no problem. I have tried to put things like `AssetImage` or `FileImage` inside `DecorationImage`, but it seems like none of them work for me.

My code is basically as below:

```
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
    body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                image: new DecorationImage(
                  image: new AssetImage('assets\\test.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
   );
```

What should I do for my `test.png` to show? Currently I just see an empty screen.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to give `width` and `height` to your `Container`, like this

```
new Container(
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    image: new DecorationImage(
      image: new AssetImage('assets\\test.png'),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have been trying it with DecoratedBox and apparently I can't set height and width to it.

Answer (score 1):

just wrong way..  use this  => "/"          not this => "\"

`image: DecorationImage( image: AssetImage("lib/assets/images/aksam_gece.png"), fit: BoxFit.fill, ),`

also check pubspec path